# What is the exact command name to invoke an apt-get install downloaded package?

Tags: 14.04

After no success with the standard "Ubuntu download center" attempt to download
the (trivial) scientific-calculator package, I do
sudo apt-get install scientific-calculator  & this seems to work fine!

I type the command-
scientific-calculator
and "scientific-calculator: Command not found" .
Nowhere on the "Ubuntu download center", or anywhere else I can find, is the
exact command name required to invoke this program.

How do I find the exact command name necessary to invoke the program?

Note: This is not localized to the scientific-calculator package. The same problem
for anything downloaded via "Ubuntu download center" or apt-get.

Thanx, even-though-I-am-stupid,
Jim V

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 which doesn't come with the Ubuntu Software Center but this is how I'd go about things.

Run

```
apt-cache search scientific | grep calculator
```

You may see more or less than the following entries depending on which software sources you have enabled and if paid apps are included:

```
gnome-calculator - GNOME desktop calculator
calcoo - Scientific calculator (GTK+)
edenmath.app - Scientific calculator for GNUstep
galculator - scientific calculator
kcalc - simple and scientific calculator
wcalc - Flexible command-line scientific calculator
```

Finding the command to run is simple if the line refers to an executable. It's the word (or words separated by a hyphen) to the left of the " - " (note the spaces).

On my system, I'd run `galculator` from the terminal to access a scientific calculator because that's what I have on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can always view the list of files installed by some package, and executables are typically in a `bin` folder:

```
$ dpkg -L software-center | grep bin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin/software-center-gtk3
/usr/bin/software-center
/usr/sbin/update-software-center
```

So, to run Software Centre, I'd use `software-center` or `software-center-gtk3` as the command.

However, `scientific-calculator` is not a package from [the official repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=scientific-calculator). So how `sudo apt-get install scientific-calculator` worked is a mystery to me.